# Installing Xen without an O.S.

Tags: xen

Is it possible to install Xen Hypervisor directly on bare metal, without a host O.S.
Xen is ssaid to be a bare metal hypervisor but ,I'vent found any image files regarding Xen.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible as Xen is **bear metal hyper-visor**.
I am also working on Xen and i have done it smoothly.

You can find an ISO image at below link
http://xenserver.org/open-source-virtualization-download.html